# Make a TextView Editable in a Launcher Widget (Android)

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm trying to create a launcher widget with a TextView that is editable. Everything I read says that android:editable is deprecated, so I haven't played with that much (even though it didn't look like that worked anyway).

This is what the xml for the TextView looks like:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/hours_textview"
          android:text="@string/zero"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
          android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
          android:padding="10dip"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
                      android:layout_width="50dip" 
                      android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                      android:inputType="number" 
                      android:typeface="serif" 
                      android:clickable="true" 
                      android:cursorVisible="true" 
                      android:digits="0123456789" 
                      android:focusable="true" 
                      android:selectAllOnFocus="true"/>
```

I'm pretty new to android developement so I'm probably missing something obvious. I'm not running any code to process the widget at this point. Do I need to set any event handlers to capture a tap and trigger the editing process? If so ... which events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Editable text fields are not supported in Launcher app widgets.

Comment: How does the google search bar or twitter widgets, etc work? Are they complete custom widgets?

Comment: They don't let you enter text directly inside the widget, they just launch an activity.